# How to get the GUID of a table in microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

In Access, when I do a Database Tools->Database Documenter, and document an existing table, the report has a value called GUID.  I want to get that GUID programatically.

I am trying to determine if 2 databases came from the same source, by comparing their GUID.

Points for either telling me the name of the function;  alternately, you could tell me how to decompile the code that generates the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value can be found in the system table called MySysNameMap

```
SELECT GUID FROM MySysNameMap WHERE Name = "Your TABLE NAME"
```

You can also use function such as DLookup in VBA to get the GUID from that system table.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Access 2010, the GUID value is in the "Properties" section of the Database Documenter report, so I tried this out in one of my databases:

```
CurrentDB.TableDefs("dateTest").Properties("GUID").Value
```

The return value is an Array of Bytes.